# Finding button by id and change itself width

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to correct button's width automaticly, but for it, I think, I need to use code like below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
val button_main=findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_main)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            button_main.setWidth = width / 3
        }
}
```

Unfortunately , if I use this method, I can't start app, but have no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code with below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()         
    val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    lateinit var button_main:Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button_main = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_main)
        button_main.setWidth = width / 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot search for button_main prior calling setContentView(). Move init of that val to onCreate(). Also, always read crash stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear i see you want to change your button's width i suggest you to use scale animation first you will create an anim folder inside res and create an anim file
and change it's size(width and height) over any time **(3 seconds 5 seconds whatever you want)** there is a link how to use scale animation from android developer.com
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation

```
  <scale
            android:fromXScale="float"
            android:toXScale="float"
            android:fromYScale="float"
            android:toYScale="float"
            android:pivotX="float"
            android:pivotY="float"
            android:duration="time (miliseconds)"
 />
```

this is the pseudo code of your anim file's appearance